# ProviderError: Error: Transaction reverted: function selector was not recognized and there's no fallback function

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts, truffle, hardhat

I'm trying to call a function[propose] from Openzeppelin governor.sol. The function is like this...

```
function propose(
        address[] memory targets,
        uint256[] memory values,
        bytes[] memory calldatas,
        string memory description
    ) public virtual override returns (uint256) {
        require(
            getVotes(msg.sender, block.number - 1) >= proposalThreshold(),
            "GovernorCompatibilityBravo: proposer votes below proposal threshold"
        );

    uint256 proposalId = hashProposal(targets, values, calldatas, keccak256(bytes(description)));

    require(targets.length == values.length, "Governor: invalid proposal length");
    require(targets.length == calldatas.length, "Governor: invalid proposal length");
    require(targets.length > 0, "Governor: empty proposal");

    ProposalCore storage proposal = _proposals[proposalId];
    require(proposal.voteStart.isUnset(), "Governor: proposal already exists");

    uint64 snapshot = block.number.toUint64() + votingDelay().toUint64();
    uint64 deadline = snapshot + votingPeriod().toUint64();

    proposal.voteStart.setDeadline(snapshot);
    proposal.voteEnd.setDeadline(deadline);

    emit ProposalCreated(
        proposalId,
        _msgSender(),
        targets,
        values,
        new string[](targets.length),
        calldatas,
        snapshot,
        deadline,
        description
    );

    return proposalId;
}
```

I've used this function in my different contract like this...

```
function propose(
    address[] memory targets,
    uint256[] memory values,
    bytes[] memory calldatas,
    string memory description
  ) public override(Governor, IGovernor) returns (uint256) {
    return super.propose(targets, values, calldatas, description);
  }
```

finally, after successfully deploying it and when it comes to using it for a function proposal, I'm using the Box.sol's store function to govern on.

```
// Stores a new value in the contract
  function store(uint256 newValue) public onlyOwner {
    value = newValue;
    emit ValueChanged(newValue);
  }
```

First I made the, function selector like this...

```
const governor = await ethers.getContract("GovernorContract");
const box = await ethers.getContract("Box");

const encodedFunctionCall = box.interface.encodeFunctionData('store', [77]);
```

and on consoling, I'm getting this selector in bytes...

```
0x6057361d000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000004d
```

Now, I'm calling the propose function...

```
const proposeTx = await governor.propose(
        [box.address],
        [0],
        [encodedFunctionCall],
        proposalDescription
    );
```

But here, I'm getting the error...

```
Error: Transaction reverted: function selector was not recognized and there's no fallback function
      at Box.<unrecognized-selector> (contracts/Box.sol:6)
```

Actually, it is not recognizing the store function of box.sol. I've already compiled the contract many time, but getting the same error.